# Path Finding Algo using BFS does not make my character move

Tags: java, path-finding, breadth-first-search

Kinda messed up the spacing haha but the methods bfs up to the last method belongs to LyannaMormont class. This is from a machine problem given by our professor. Basically the game has a hero, creeps, consumables and equipments. Our professor provided us with some javadocs containing the methods we need. Locatable object can be any of those four(hero, creep, consumable, equipment). I can basically get the x and y location of a locatable to find a path to it by setting it as the destination attribute and then getting the path using bfs() and then moving the character (in this case, i created the go method, which has moveUp(), moveDown(), moveRight(), moveLeft() methods which was included in the javadocs and does exactly what their names suggests). The action method contains all the things that the character does. My problem is that, the character is not moving when I activate the jar file of the game. Is there something wrong with the code? If there is, can someone please tell me where? I'm basically stuck in this problem for 3 days now. Any help/suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks :)

**NOTE:**
WorldState w = getWorld(); returns a copy of the world my character is in. w.isPassable(int x, int y) returns true if I can walk through (x,y) and false otherwise.

```
import com.th.*;
import java.util.*;


public class LyannaMormont extends HeroBot{
    ArrayList<Node> way = new ArrayList<Node>();
    private Locatable destination;
    private int count = 0;
    private boolean where = false;
    private final int counter = 0;

    public class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
        private int xPosition;
        private int yPosition;
        private Node parentNode;
        private double minDist;

        public Node(int x, int y, Node p, double n){
            this.xPosition = x;
            this.yPosition = y;
            this.parentNode = p;
            this.minDist = n;
        }

        public int getXPosition(){
            return this.xPosition;
        }

        public int getYPosition(){
            return this.yPosition;
        }

        public void setXPosition(int x){
            this.xPosition = x;
        }

        public void setYPosition(int y){
            this.yPosition = y;
        }

        public Node getParentNode(){
            return this.parentNode;
        }

        public void setParentNode(Node p){
            this.parentNode = p;
        }

        public double getMinDist(){
            return this.minDist;
        }

        public void setMinDist(double m){
            this.minDist = m;
        }

        public int compareTo(Node otherNode){
            return Double.compare(this.minDist, otherNode.getMinDist());
        }

        public boolean equals(Node node){
            if((this.xPosition == node.getXPosition())&&(this.yPosition == node.getYPosition())){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void bfs(){
        WorldState w = getWorld();
        ArrayList<Node> found = new ArrayList<Node>();
        Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
        Node source = new Node(this.getXLocation(), this.getYLocation(), null, 0.0);
        queue.add(source);
        found.add(source);
        ArrayList<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();

        outerloop:
        while(queue.peek()!=null){
            Node node = queue.poll();
            if((node.getXPosition() == this.destination.getXLocation())&&(node.getYPosition() == this.destination.getYLocation())){
                path.add(node);
                queue.clear();
                found.clear();
                break outerloop;
            }

            int x = node.getXPosition();
            int y = node.getYPosition();
            if(w.isPassable(x-1, y)){
                Node newNode = new Node(x-1, y, node, node.getMinDist() + 1.0);
                if(!found.contains(newNode)){
                    queue.add(newNode);
                    found.add(newNode);
                }
            }
            if(w.isPassable(x, y-1)){
                Node newNode = new Node(x, y-1, node, node.getMinDist() + 1.0);
                if(!found.contains(newNode)){
                    queue.add(newNode);
                    found.add(newNode);
                }
            }
            if(w.isPassable(x+1, y)){
                Node newNode = new Node(x+1, y, node, node.getMinDist() + 1.0);
                if(!found.contains(newNode)){
                    queue.add(newNode);
                    found.add(newNode);
                }
            }
            if(w.isPassable(x, y+1)){
                Node newNode = new Node(x, y+1, node, node.getMinDist() + 1.0);
                if(!found.contains(newNode)){
                    queue.add(newNode);
                    found.add(newNode);
                }
            }
        }
        Node goal = path.get(0);
        this.way = new ArrayList<Node>();
        while(goal.getParentNode()!=null){
            this.way.add(0, goal);
            goal = goal.getParentNode();
        }
        if (goal.getParentNode() == null){
            this.way.add(0, goal);
        }
        Collections.sort(this.way);
        this.destination = null;
        this.where = false;
    }
```

Comment: This might be easier to read an answer if you got rid of all of the code that not relevant to be specific question.

Comment: You are returning regardless which path you take in `outerloop`, so it will only ever run once and return from `public void bfs()`.

Comment: so should I erase the return in both paths?

Comment: Yeah, from what I understand you definitely do not want to return at those places.

Comment: Thanks bro. Just tried it but still does not work. Do you think I implemented bfs correctly?

Comment: Assuming that `queue.poll()` removes a Node from the queue, there will be nothing in the queue after the first iteration of the loop. The progress = true path only consumes a Node, so the one you initially put in will be consumed and the loop will exit the next iteration. I'll suggest some code in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some special reason for the `progress` variable, then you want to do away with it entirely. It is consuming a `Node` when you don't want it to. Essentially you want to test if you are at your goal each iteration and break if you've found it. Otherwise you branch out.

```
outerloop:
while(queue.peek()!=null){
    Node node = queue.poll();
    if((node.getXPosition() == this.destination.getXLocation())&&(node.getYPosition() == this.destination.getYLocation())){
        path.add(node);
        queue.clear();
        found.clear();
        break outerloop;
    }

    int x = node.getXPosition();
    int y = node.getYPosition();
    if(w.isPassable(x-1, y)){
        Node newNode = new Node(x-1, y, node, node.getMinDist() + 1.0);
        if(!found.contains(newNode)){
            queue.add(newNode);
            found.add(newNode);
        }
    }
    if(w.isPassable(x, y-1)){
        Node newNode = new Node(x, y-1, node, node.getMinDist() + 1.0);
        if(!found.contains(newNode)){
            queue.add(newNode);
            found.add(newNode);
        }
    }
    if(w.isPassable(x+1, y)){
        Node newNode = new Node(x+1, y, node, node.getMinDist() + 1.0);
        if(!found.contains(newNode)){
            queue.add(newNode);
            found.add(newNode);
        }
    }
    if(w.isPassable(x, y+1)){
        Node newNode = new Node(x, y+1, node, node.getMinDist() + 1.0);
        if(!found.contains(newNode)){
            queue.add(newNode);
            found.add(newNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still didn't work. Maybe I have some mistakes in some parts of my code. The game hang, so I assume I hit on some infinite loop or what. Still helped, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: There are tons of implementations of Dijkstra's algorithm for shortest path. Just do a google search. From what I can tell, the loop should work, but obviously I can't see the whole picture. Toss a print statement in the loop to see if that's where it is getting hung up.

Comment: Yup about Dijkstra, I can't understand how I could implement it into my game. Can you please explain what is their difference?(Dijkstra and BFS) because I dont really understand all these explanations from different websites lol

Comment: From your code, it looks like all your branches have a cost of `1.0`. If all the edges have the same weight, then Dijkstra's is the same as BFS anyway. The only real difference between the two is that with BFS, you consider a node and push all it's edges. In Dijkstra's, you do the same, but you push to a priority queue, which orders them by distance and spits out the one with the least distance next.

Comment: Here is a link to my professor's notes on BFS and Dijkstra. You'll notice the only difference is the special mention of the priority queue methods. In his BFS example, it is just a straightforward FIFO queue. Note that his code examples don't have a destination to find. His specific code finds ALL shortest paths from the starting location. You are looking for a specific location, so you will want to check for it as you have been doing.

http://cit.dixie.edu/cs/3510/examples.examples/Lecture-y16m02d25p04-in-class-bfs-dijkstra.pdf

Comment: Oh, now I get it. This is really helpful. Thanks a lot for explaining man, really appreciate it :)